# Angular Flex Layout with column

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

How can I adjust the width of the child component in a fxLayout set to column. For e.g. take this e.g.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fxlayout-custom-breakpoints?file=app%2Ftest.component.ts

Here the author has three fxFlex. How can I set the width of the yellow colour to half of the available area. When I try to change the fxFlex for e.g. to 30 the height is getting updated but I want the width. What am I missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get changing of height instead of width because with of window is too less, and  fxLayout.xs="column" is started to work.

If you wish make your second section 50% you need to set fxFlex="50" for second section and fxFlex for others.

If you wish not to change size (height) for small screen when the order changes to column, you can declare fxFlex.xs without options.

If you wish not to change order(row to column) just delete fxLayout.xs="column" option.

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fxlayout-custom-breakpoints-kbcsr5?file=app%2Ftest.component.ts
Just change screen size to see

[image]

[image]

Comment: in a fxLayout = column with fixed screensize. How can I change the width of each child elements in it. Say I have 4 child element one below each other with different width